# Add meta descriptions to tag search pages

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, seo

Add a meta description to the tag pages such as [Firewall](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/firewall) to avoid this ugliness:

[image]

The text can simply read:

> Questions tagged firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it should pick up the title element already:

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/firewall
```

has this title

```
<title>Newest &#39;firewall&#39; Questions - Server Fault</title>
```